# How to add categories in a static Block?

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block

How can I add categories to a static block so that I can call that block in my footer section.
[image]

the above image is from footer and I want to insert all my categories there.

Comment: are you want to show this  block on category page footer

Comment: please have a look at my edited content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put this in a new file say `footer_categories.phtml`:

```
<div class="footer_categories">
          <ul>
               <?php $helper = $this->helper('catalog/category') ?>
             <?php foreach ($helper->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
             <li>
                 <a href="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setData($_category->getData())->getUrl(); ?>" title="<?php echo $_category->getName() ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName() ?></a>
             </li>
             <?php endforeach ?>
          </ul>

    </div>
     <?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
```

Now open your static block and call in this way

```
{{block type="core/template" template="catalog/footer_categories.phtml"}}
```

you can get the required output.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you added some php code directly in the static block.
That won't work. Magento does not support php in the static blocks. And that's a good thing.
It only supports html and `{{}}` directives.
So what you need to do is to create a template file. Let's call it `footer_categories.phtml` You can place it in `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/footer_categories.phtml` where you place the code you added directly in the block.
Then edit the static block and replace the code you added with this:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="catalog/footer_categories.phtml"}}
```

**[EDIT]**
Here is the code you need to place in the template

```
<?php 
$root = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1) //only active categories
    ->setOrder('position', 'ASC');
?>
<?php foreach ($categories as $category) :?>
    <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl();?>"><?php echo $category->getName();?></a>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Of course this may look ugly but you can handle the css part.

Comment: and can you please tell me what code added to footer_categories.phtml to get all the categories.

Comment: By the looks of your screenshot I think you already have the code. Please post in the question the code you added directly in the static block and I'll tell you if it's ok or not.

Comment: actually I followed the procedure mentioned by zack in his answer and it resulted in that way :(

Comment: You want all the categories or only the top level ones?

Comment: Only the main categories no sub categories

Comment: @Abdul See my update to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow simple step might helps you.**

1)Create a static block for the content you want to use between categories.

2)Now go back to manage categories, and find your category

3)Select display mode “Static block and products”

4)Select the static block you created in step 1. The static block will appear above the list of products.

**Get collection of all active categories:**

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

**Get collection of all active categories within a subcategory:**

```
$parentCategoryId = '9';
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', array('eq'=>$parentCategoryId))
    ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', array('eq'=>'1'))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

**Get collection of all active and inactive categories within a subcategory:**

```
$parentCategoryId = '9';
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', array('eq'=>$parentCategoryId))
    ->addFieldToFilter('is_active',array("in"=>array('0', '1')))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

**Get collection of all inactive categories within a subcategory:**

```
$parentCategoryId = '9';
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
     ->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', array('eq'=>$parentCategoryId))
    ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', array('neq'=>'1'))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Comment: please have a look at my edited content

Comment: Can you make this answer clearer - it appears to suggest using PHP in the static block with will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If want to call you category static blogon category then just call

below code at footer.phtml

```
  if(Mage::registry('current_category')){
        if(Mage::registry('current_category')->getLandingPage()):

         $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')
                ->setBlockId(Mage::registry('current_category')->getLandingPage())
                ->toHtml();
        endif;
    }
```

According to magento logic static block id save at `landing_page` field of category object

```
if($_category->getLandingPage()):
 $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')
        ->setBlockId($_category->getLandingPage())
        ->toHtml();
endif;
```

Comment: I want all my categories into a static block and then  I can call them in my footer

Comment: for ex I have categories like mens womens children all this catgories should be visible in my footer and also should have href's so when user click on mens then he shoudl get mens category page